# HTML animations

Tags: html, css, animation

I created a script to create a 300px x 300px box that is rainbow. It isn't showing anything when I try to run it. What am I doing wrong?
I have run this code against a tutorial on how to do it and haven't found anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
width: 300px;
height:300px;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation: myfirst;
animation: myfirst;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
 14%    {background-color: red;}
 28%    {background-color: orange;}
 42%    {background-color: yellow;}
 56%    {background-color: green;}
 70%    {background-color: blue;}
 84%    {background-color: #4b0082;}
 100%   {background-color: #EE82EE;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your animation keyframes are not the same. I'd start there. You also haven't specified how long the animation should be....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing the closing bracket for your keyframes animation

EDIT: you also need to add a duration of the animation like this:
`animation: 3s myfirst`